# Why my iOS App's Documents directory became a file?

Tags: ios

We are developing an iOS app with Enterprise distribution.
 It ran well in hundreds of devices, but we found some iOS 6.1.3 devices failed to launch it hours later the first run, because the App's Documents directory became a file !

Our App did nothing special except it was downloading about 80MB MP4 files from a remote HTTP server.

I assumed that something wrong when it operated the Documents directory, but so far have little clue to identify what's 'dangerous' usage in our codes.

Did you have encountered similar problems? How did you fix it?

Thanks a lot to anybody kindly helping to figure it out.

Comment: A bug in your app can cause this. Perhaps you deleted the Documents folders and then wrote a file giving it the name of Documents.

Comment: No, no code tried to delete the Documents folder. with more test result, we suspected the folder corrupted while the App was upgrading and downloading MP4 at the same time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest doing is for your app to test for this when it launches, and if there is a file there, move it to some other place (like the temp folder), then create the Documents directory, then move the file back into that directory with the same name (or change the name). That will at least prevent your app from stalling.

If you have any means of remote logging, you could bin hex the first 64 bytes of the file and send it to your service for analysis (if you know what's in the file it should help you figure out who created it.)

Comment: The file should not be created by any code. Was it possible to corrupt    if App upgrading and folder writting happened at the same time?

Comment: @firebear at least in the past you could create and move these directories. In fact the Application Support dir was not even created for you. My point is that ios does not block you from doing crazy things to your private file system. It could be that the "atomic" version of some standard write op might remove a dir and replace it with a file.